# Is there a way to see other player's skill distributions like in the original Payday?

Tags: payday-2

In the original Payday: The Heist, you could look at a player's name and see three bars indicating which trees they had decided to level.

**Is there a way to view similar information in Payday 2?**  For example, it would be handy to be able to tell during the planning phase if a bank job crew has three enforcers and no technicians.

Comment: Not that I've seen, something like this would be useful to know whether or not that medic has the upgraded medikit or not as well

Comment: There is the Player Lobby Info mod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of yet, there is no such option to view a players skill information.

If you want to know what the player has skilled, ask them via in-game chat.